# renaming column labels in multiindex df (built from excel)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I'm reading an excel file and manipulating the content to a pandas df.

heres what the excel content looks like (fig 1). And here's what I want the df to look like (fig 2) but with one exception - I want to rename the column labels at index level 0, "A4+" to "All Ind" and "A18-49" to "Comm Demo".

The problem I have is that when I rename the column labels they come out inverted, not sure why?

Here's is the code I use..

```
    full_path_to_excel_file = path_runs+excel_file_name+'.xls'

    df = pd.read_excel(full_path_to_excel_file, 0, header=None, index_col=0)
    df = df.iloc[11:,:]
    df = df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)

    df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df[:2].values) 

    #Just name of index
    df.index.name=None

    #remove 3 rows which are already used as column names
    df = df[pd.notnull(df.index)] 
    df = df.drop(['Channel Group ...'])
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    df.columns.set_levels(['All Ind', 'Comm Demo'], 0, inplace=True)
```

the excel i used is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvpz8p7kzpcph6q/Time%20KPI%20000s%20BG.xls?dl=0

fig1

[image]

fig 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***use `set_levels`***
consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(-1, 4),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A4+', 'A18-49'], list('XY')]))
df
```

[image]

---

```
m = {'A4+': 'All Ind', 'A18-49': 'Comm Demo'}
df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.levels[0].to_series().map(m), level=0, inplace=True)
df
```

[image]